# is this set finite, infinitely countable, or uncountable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

the set that contains everyone on an island who may say "I'm not a knight", given that the island only has knights who ALWAYS tell the truth and knaves who ALWAYS lie.
so how many people can say "I’m not a knight"?

Would the set be empty and thus finite? since no knight can say "I’m not a knight" bc that would be a lie, and they never lie. and no knave can say "I’m not a knight" because that would be the truth and they always lie.

is this correct? if not, can you explain?

Comment: Yes, there is no one on that island who is able to say "I am not a knight".

Comment: what is the relation between the question and group theory ? I think logic and puzzle tags would be appropriate

Comment: Can the person who asserted that the island only has knights and knaves say this? Also I would generally say that any set of people should be regarded as finite. If the point is to use the "people" as allegorical cover for some logical/mathematical entities, it's better to drop the charade and talk directly.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. It's a standard logic puzzle. Smullyan wrote a few books of this kind of puzzle. Here's a website with more info: https://www.futurelearn.com/info/courses/recreational-math/0/steps/43522

Comment: @Joffan it's a question from my discrete math class, straight from the cardinality of sets chapter and I wanted to confirm my understanding so it’s not a charade

Comment: @Joffan It looks like it's just a riddle. Perhaps consider turning down a notch the tone in the comments. Thanks,

Comment: @Pedro not sure what triggered your remark about tone, can you explain?

Comment: @MichaelWeiss thanks for the link but I have been a fan of Smullyan for decades :)

Comment: @eshtabel3asal I wasn't referring to anything you said as a charade, just the format of the question. Lulu answered specifically and correctly, as usual, so my remarks were more general and exploratory.

Comment: @Joffan I may have misinterpreted your comment, but " If the point is to use the "people" as allegorical cover for some logical/mathematical entities, it's better to **drop the charade and talk directly**." seems like a confusing ask (emphasis mine). Word problems are designed to provide such "allegorical cover", and most of the times solving them requires to translate them into logic and/or mathematics, i.e. this is part of the task or what might be confusing the OP.

Comment: @Pedro the answer to the specific question, already given before my comment, is an empty set. My point was basically that any question aspiring to have infinite sets within the answer possibilities should not be using people of any sort as set members. And if they do, it's a bad question.